# React Native Community Webview renderError() always returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-webview, expo, react-native-webview

I'm executing the code below as mentioned in the docs while I'm disconnected to the internet.

```
renderError={errorName => <Error name={errorName} />}
```

I'm expecting the name prop to be something like connection error but it is **undefined**.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: This happens to me as well. Did you manage to solve it?